# How can I fade in text-decoration css with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
This is a <span id="sentence">sentence</span>.
```

When a user hovers over `sentence`, I would like an underline to fade in under the word.

This seems like such a simple problem, but I have not been able to figure out how best to do it. Just to be clear, I cannot just use `css:hover`. I need to do this with JQuery given the actual problem is more complicated and requires more control than that illustrated here. Thanks very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [Animated Underlines with jQuery](http://cavaliere.org/sandbox/jquery_animated_underline_plugin) plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but tried and failed unfortunately. Here's a js fiddle (just fading on load rather than hover) of what should work, but doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/as42u/  Any other ideas? This should definitely work -- so frustrating, but I really hope I just made a stupid mistake and this is easily fixable.

Comment: Hrm... Your fiddle looks like it should work. I think the plugin is old though. If you can do it in CSS (see other answer) I would lean towards that as it is more standard (although may not be as backwards compatible).

Comment: @Andrew Good news -- you were just missing the styles. Your fiddle works with styles: http://jsfiddle.net/as42u/3/

Answer (score 4):

This might not fit your needs, and I realize you specifically don't want to use CSS.  But just in case...

#### HTML

```
This is a <span id="sentence">sentence.</span>​
```

#### CSS

```
span {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

span.clicked {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}​
```

#### Script

```
$('span').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/as42u/4/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I do need to do it with jquery, but really appreciate the contribution.

Comment: @Andrew Why do you "need" to do it with jQuery?

Comment: A good reason would be it needs to work in a browser that does not suport [CSS transition](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) (looks like IE is the big offender). I +1 you though as CSS only is of course better if it fits the need.

Comment: Apart from the IE compatibility issue, because the hover effect should only happen under certain circumstances, not all the time. Given that, I need to be able to control when the hover happens according to a set of parameters. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Then just have jQuery add a class with new styles - see my updated answer.

Comment: It's a great solution, but you'd still run into the IE compatibility issue with css transitions.

Comment: Seems like the other answer will work, than.  It doesn't require transition support.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Use the [underline jQuery plugin](http://cavaliere.org/sandbox/jquery_animated_underline_plugin)** as Cymen suggested

Don't forget to add the [required CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/as42u/5/) to your stylesheet

**2. Do it yourself**

```
$("#sentence").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        borderBottomWidth: "1px"
    }, 500);
});
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as42u/6/). You have to use a bottom border because jQuery doesn't know how to animate the text-decoration property.