# Is it possible to animate a CSS line-through text-decoration?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to animate with CSS the a line through on a bit of text, but it's not actually animating, just going from hidden to displayed. Can anyone advise if what I'm trying is actually possible? If not, is there another way to achieve this?
HTML:

```
<div>
    The text in the span <span class="strike">is what I want to strike out</span>.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes strike{
                from{text-decoration: none;}
                to{text-decoration: line-through;}
            }
 .strike{  
    -webkit-animation-name: strike; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: strike;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    }
```

Comment: Probably can't use text-decoration.  But you should be able to fudge it by overlaying and positioning say a 1px height div with a border and animate the width of the div.

Comment: Have you noticed that you can't actually tell the browser what you want the animation to look like? Neither does the browser know. So it doesn't try.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a pseudo like this

*Note (thanks to [Phlame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267507/is-it-possible-to-animate-a-css-line-through-text-decoration/36267849?noredirect=1#comment114475894_36267849)), this left-to-right animation won't work if the line to strike breaks in to a second line. For that one need to use yet another pseudo element and some script to position the two properly. Or use some other animation effect, e.g. like the one suggested in [Oriol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36268164/2827823).*

```css
@keyframes strike{
  0%   { width : 0; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}
.strike {
  position: relative;
}
.strike::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  animation-name: strike;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    The text in the span <span class="strike">is what I want to strike out</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: Provided you aren't concerned about some older browser support (due to `animations` and `pseudo` element) this would be the way to go. Nice solution LGSon

Comment: Just a warning: this won't work if the text breaks on to another line

Comment: @Phlame -- So true, thanks, updated my answer with a note.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on how you want to animate it.

Since [`text-decoration-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color) is animatable, you can animate it from `transparent` to `auto`.

But this property is not widely supported yet.

```css
@keyframes strike {
  from { text-decoration-color: transparent; }
  to { text-decoration-color: auto; }
}
.strike {  
  text-decoration: line-through;
  animation: strike 4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
    The text in the span <span class="strike">is what I want to strike out</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: It works on Firefox and Chromium with some experimental flag.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation on the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267849/8112776) answer, using an image to provide an animated  "scribble" strike-through.

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.strike { position:relative; }
.strike::after {
  content:' ';
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:-3%;
  width:0; height:10px;
  opacity:80%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  background:repeat-x url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB0AAAAKAQMAAAByjsdvAAAABlBMVEUAAADdMzNrjRuKAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAADdJREFUCNdj+MMABP8ZGCQY/h9g+MHw/AHzDwbGD+w/GBhq6h8wMNj/b2BgkP8HVMMPUsn+gQEAsTkQNRVnI4cAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
  animation: strike 2s linear .3s 1 forwards;
}
@keyframes strike { to { width: 106%; } }
```

```html
This thing and <span class="strike">this thing and</span> this thing.
```

Comment: This is amazing, but I do not think that this is answer of this question. I know you can use strike through ( straight line image ) image instead of scribble image but...

Answer (score 3):

It's very elegant, IMO, to use `linear-gradient` as background, and paint line which is the same color as the text (`currentColor`).

This solution is very flexible, opens up the door to many interesting effects and is also much less code than a pseudo-element solution.

*PS: It also supports multi-line texts*

### From my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/KKQoVRZ):

```css
span {
  --thickness: .1em;
  --strike: 0;
  
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, currentColor 0) no-repeat 
              right center / calc(var(--strike) * 100%) var(--thickness);

  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font: 25px Arial;
  padding: 0 .2em;
}

span:hover {
  --strike: 1; /* "1" means "true" (show the strike line) */
  background-position-x: left;
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable spellcheck='false'>
  Strike-through animation (hover)
 </span>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with multi-line texts; did I miss something?
https://codepen.io/TTvanWillegen/pen/xxzJzWN

Comment: @TobyvWillegen It is because of `display: grid;`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to find a way around it that also work for multiple lines, I mainly got this info from Kevin Powell's code pen:https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/MWYwgOz. Here's my solution

```css
.fancy-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: 0% 1px;
  transition: background-size 500ms ease-in-out;

  /* extra styling   */
/*   font-weight: var(--fw-bold); */
}

.fancy-link:hover {
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p> <a class="fancy-link" href="#">sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit repudiandae assumenda beatae Impedit repudiandae assumenda beatae Impedit repudiandae assumenda beatae Impedit repudiandae assumenda beatae quo iure quaerat voluptate placeat. A eius cum, rem aspernatur ipsa illum. Commodi ullam cupiditate aliquid ducimus consequatur.</a></p>
</div>
```

Also, for accessibility issues, you can add

```css
.fancy-link:hover{
  /*...former code*/
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration-color:transparent;
}
```

Note: the "fancy-link" class isn't on the paragraph tag but on the anchor tag.

Answer (score -1):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-decoration.asp), the `text-decoration` property is not animatable.

However, if you use jQuery, you can. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775327/how-can-i-fade-in-text-decoration-css-with-jquery))

Comment: I prefer to reference Mozilla's documentation than W3, so I'll drop this link here as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration