# Animated CSS strikethrough text decoration

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72459455/14512582). Obviously the red line is behind the text due to the use of `background`. How to achieve the same effect (with multiline support) with the red line in front of the text?

```css
span {
  --thickness: .1em;
  --strike: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, red 0) no-repeat 
              right center / calc(var(--strike) * 100%) var(--thickness);
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

span:hover {
  --strike: 1;
  background-position-x: left;
}
```

```html
<span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
 </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can color the text using background as well by considering `background-clip`

```css
span {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat 
    left / var(--s,0%) .1em,
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box, text;
          background-clip: border-box, text;
  color: #0000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

span:hover {
  --s: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
 </span>
```

Comment: That's smart! Thank you! Is it even possible to shift the line up or down a little?

Comment: @ThreeYearOlds instead of `left` use `0 50%` and then adjust the 50% to move up or down

Comment: Great! `0 60%` works well. Thank you and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Could you please explain what `color: #0000` is all about? With `color: #000` it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: @ThreeYearOld you should only update the colors within the background property. The `color` need to remain transparent (`#0000` is transparent)

Comment: Thank you very much for your lightning-fast response. I just didn't know the four-value syntax, where `#RGBA` is equivalent to `#RRGGBBAA` and where `A` or `AA` reflects the alpha component.. So `color: transparent` might be clearer to understand. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Would you kindly take a look at my edit?

Comment: @ThreeYearOld don't edit your question to include my answer or another question. You should not change the meaning of the question and you should not use the question as way to discuss solutions

Comment: I posted it as a new question.

Comment: It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121630/animated-css-strikethrough-text-decoration-with-multiple-text-colors). I would be happy to shove more reputation points to you. ;)