# Animated CSS strikethrough text decoration with multiple text colors

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78088612/14512582). What if there is more than one color needed to be strikethrough?

```css
span {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red 0 0) no-repeat 
    0 60% / var(--s,0%) .1em,
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box, text;
          background-clip: border-box, text;
  color: #0000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

span:hover {
  --s: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by more color? means instead of red you need other color for strikethrough?

Comment: Do you mean you want the strike through color to be the same as the underlying text color?

Comment: @Leothelion No. Because of the link within the span there are two text colors, one for the link and one for the normal text. The red line is behind the link text instead of in front of it.

Comment: @AHaworth No. Because of the link within the span there are two text colors, one for the link and one for the normal text. The red line is behind the link text instead of in front of it.

Comment: you need to make the color of the link transparent as well, it's not by default

Comment: @TemaniAfif But then the link text has the same color as the normal text. Plus the link underline is lost.

Comment: So is the question simply how to get the strike through in front of all the text? I can’t see that is has anything to do with color (other than you can see the red is behind the blue which you wouldn’t notice if they were both black).

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, that's exactly what it's about.

Comment: @ThreeYearOld you want this https://jsfiddle.net/dqn2smyx/

Comment: @Leothelion No. What makes you think that? I simply want the red line to appear in front of both the link text and the normal text, not behind it. The color of the link text should still be different from the color of the normal text.

Comment: @ThreeYearOld so you want to have red line in front of text? check this plz  https://jsfiddle.net/ky1Lagv5/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ThreeYearOld you have accepted an answer - does it do everything you want? (I  thought you wanted to keep the anchor text as blue for example).

Comment: @AHaworth Actually yes. But I would prefer a solution without `z-index`.

Comment: @AHaworth I must correct myself. It doesn't work as desired because the `z-index` means that the link is no longer clickable.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Any chance that you reveal the solution?

Comment: @ThreeYearOld I understand you need the link to be still clickable, but do you also require it to keep its original color (blue in this case for 'standard' links)?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

As after discussion in the comment box, here is the solution.

Just use `position:relative` on the text and put `z-index:-999` so your text will be behind the red line(strikethrough).

Working example :

```css
span {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0 0) no-repeat 
    0 60% / var(--s,0%) .1em,
    #000;
  -webkit-background-clip: border-box, text;
          background-clip: border-box, text;
  color: #0000;
  transition: background-size .4s ease;
  font-size: 1.5em;
 
  
}

span:hover {
  --s: 100%;  
}

a{
  position:relative;
  z-index:-999;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</a> At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
</span>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Is there even a solution without the nasty `z-index`? Keyword: [accessibility](https://danielrotter.at/2020/04/08/avoid-z-index-whenever-possible.html).

Comment: But this seems to get rid of the color on the anchor element, which I had thought was the difficulty.

Comment: @AHaworth sorry but did not get you? You want to remove the color of a tag too? or what?

Comment: With `z-index:-999` the link is no longer clickable.

Comment: Sorry din see that you need animation too. Working on it.

Comment: @Leothelion Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: @ThreeYearOld sorry mate was busy in some work. will check today and will let you know.